# Running Concatenation on String

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
    Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4
    WEST     WHEAT    0        abc
    WEST     WHEAT    0        def
    WEST     WHEAT    1        ghi
    WEST     WHEAT    1        jkl
    WEST     WHEAT    2        mno
    WEST     WHEAT    2        pqr
```

The data in the above table is grouped based on the columns Column1, Column2 and Column3,
and Column4 has to be concatenated.

The expected concatenated Column4 output is as follows:

```
abc,def
abc,def,ghi,jkl
abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno,pqr
```

Using the Following the code the Column4 values are concatenated

```
    STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + "Column4" FROM "Query2" Q2 WHERE Q1."Column1"=Q2."Column1" and MainQuery."Column2"=Q2."Column2" AND MainQuery."Column3"=Q2."Column3"  for xml path('')),1,1,'')
```

But the output achieved is:

```
abc,def
ghi,jkl
mno,pqr
```

The previous group values have to be concatenated with the current group values.

Can anyone pls help to achieve the expected output in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the `MainQuery."Column3" = Q2."Column3"` to `MainQuery."Column3" >= Q2."Column3"`

So your co-related query becomes

```
 STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + "Column4" FROM "Query2" Q2 WHERE Q1."Column1"=Q2."Column1" and MainQuery."Column2"=Q2."Column2" AND MainQuery."Column3" >= Q2."Column3"  for xml path('')),1,1,'')
```

This will get previous and current `Column3` values as well for the same `Column1` and `Column2`